# Form with dropdown not storing selected value

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm building a cart for a small marketplace project.

The dropdown population is working correctly but when selecting and storing the option always the last option is being stored, no matter which option is actually selected.

```
<form action="{{ route ('cart.add', $item->id )}}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputState"></label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="product_type" id="">
                                        <option>-- Elige opción -- </option>
                                            @foreach ($allProducts as $item)
                                                @if ($product->name == $item->name && $item->type == 4)
                                                    <option value="{{$item->description}}">{{$item->description}}</option>
                                                @endif
                                            @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="container fluid">
                                    <p data-aos="fade-up">
                                      <button type="submit"
                                              class="btn-ml btn-primary mr-md-2 mr-0 mb-3 d-sm-inline">
                                              Añade al carrito
                                      </button>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

I believe that the problem is in the view. Anyway, here's the logic:

```
public function add (Product $product) {

        // dd ($product);

        \Cart::add(array(
            'id' => $product->id,
            'name' => $product->description,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'attributes' => array(),
            'associatedModel' => $product
        ));

        return redirect ('/');
    }
```

Why it's storing the same -last- option despite other selected?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: While storing you are not mapping ```product_type```. Please check and update code.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the value you are passing isn't mapping the way you are expecting because you are not using any of the request data which your are passing in the form. You are only using what is coming from the database in the Product, which is different from your form.

In your logic change:

```
'name' => $product->description,
```

To this:

```
'name' => request()->input('product_type'),
```

Comment: Thanks Azeame. But the description is what I want to map. I'm capturing the `$product->id` whithin the route action in the form. Anyway, I tried your solution and It still capturing the last item of the option form...